# How to create directories with google spread sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, spreadsheet

```
import os
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = '1kUvTVkvMJOJ6Mqo7h3F_acUMsErulZvpMGTyWQxeaQM'
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv")
print(df)

root = f'D:/Project/Zee/SRGMP/Production/3D'

with open(r'D:\project\Copy of rk', 'r') as file:
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in csvfile:
        set_name = row['set_name']
        asset_name = row['assest_name']

        fixed_internal_folder = ['wip', 'export']
        for folder in fixed_internal_folder:
            asset_root = f'{root}/{set_name}/asset/{asset_name}/{folder}/'

            os.makedirs(asset_root)
            print(asset_root)
    if not os.path.exists(asset_root):
        os.makedirs(asset_root)
    else:
        os.removedirs(asset_root)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are seeing?

Comment: Seconding what Matt said. What's the error? Also, what does the sheet look like? `row['assest_name']` looks like a typo to me but I don't know for sure since there's no sheet sample.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.